# Formula For Homebrew Gasket Remover

Tags: cleaning, gasket

I looked around many shops in my area, and pretty much no one even knew what gasket removing compound was.

Are there any effective homebrew formulas for making gasket remover / softener?

I found [the MSDS for Permatex](http://www.permatex.com/component/documents/?view=msds&format=raw&filename=80645.pdf&language=01_USA-English) and [for CRC Gasket Remover](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/866081.pdf).

Comment: Did you try paint thinner?

Comment: No, but I've got naptha in the house which is pretty similar I guess, and it's a minor ingredient in one of the products I linked to.  Guess I could give it a try.

Comment: Acetone would probably work pretty good. Get some finger nail polish remover and try that on for size.

Comment: I tried the Naptha and that didn't work at all

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes be good to accept or something this question so it is not perennially pushed by the community...

Answer (score 0):

Seems it would depend on type of gasket, fiber, cork or paper. Old fashioned scraping with a gasket scraper or a razor blade for the big chunks. I use die grinder with pads for the rest. Wire wheels also but not too crazy about becoming a pin cushion.

Comment: I find Duck Oil with elbow grease works...

Answer (score 0):

Heat. I burn them off with a torch. Any carbon left behind crumbles easily. A propane torch works great, don't use acetylene.